# How to mock the return value of a custom React hook using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking

I am aware there are similar questions to this on Stack Overflow, but no existing answers have been able to help me. I have tried many combination of jest.mock()/jest.fn() with no improvement.

I am attempting to test a React component, Messenger, which imports and uses a custom hook, useWindowSize. The custom hook returns an object with two parameters, width and height. The Messenger component will return different information based on the width and height received via useWindowSize.

I want to mock useWindowSize, so that I can pass different widths and heights to Messenger and make assertions about the results shown to the user.

In my code below, I would expect that the mock would replace any return value from  useWindowSize() with my hardcoded value (width of 800). However, this is not happening.

**Messenger Component**

```
import React from "react";

import useWindowSize from "../../hooks/useWindowSize/useWindowSize";

import Desktop from "./Desktop";
import Mobile from "./Mobile";

function Messenger() {
  
  const screenSize = useWindowSize();
 
  if (screenSize.width < 768) {
    return (
      <Mobile />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Desktop /> // inside Desktop component is a div with a test-id: "test-messenger-desktop"
    );
  }
}

export default Messenger;
```

**useWindowSize custom React hook**

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const updateSize = () => {
      setWindowSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

    updateSize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
};

export default useWindowSize;
```

**Test File**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Messenger from "./Messenger";
import useWindowSize from "../../hooks/useWindowSize/useWindowSize";

jest.mock("../../hooks/useWindowSize/useWindowSize", () => ({
  useWindowSize: {
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
  },
}));


describe("Messenger", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<Messenger />);
  });

  it("renders Desktop component when screen width is greater than 800px", () => {
    const desktop = screen.getByTestId("test-messenger-desktop");
    expect(desktop).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Console output**

```
Messenger › renders Desktop component when screen width is greater than 800px

    TypeError: (0 , _useWindowSize.default) is not a function

      11 | function Messenger({ setCurrentPage }) {
      12 |   const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();
    > 13 |   const screenSize = useWindowSize();
```

Comment: What _is_ happening? A [mre] includes the output. One thing that jumps out is that the real implementation of useWindowSize is a function but the test double is an object - test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing to be any use. Another is that it's the default export, which also isn't reflected on the mock implementation.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the console output, which states that useWindowSize is not a function. The error occurs when the custom hook is invoked in the Messenger component

Comment: Sure, it's not. Your test double is an _object_, not a function.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help but I have not yet fixed this issue. I was already aware that the the mock is an object, not a function. I have previously attempted to adjust the mock to return a function like so:

jest.mock("../../hooks/useWindowSize/useWindowSize", () => ({
  default: () => {
    return {
      width: 800,
    };
  },
}));

Unless I am mistaken, I believe the above code would return a mock function in place of useWindowSize, which would return an object containing a width property of 800.

However, I am receiving the same error message as before.

Comment: I'd suggest showing _that_ as your example, then, rather than something that's trivially not going to work.